# Function is SQL

Tags: sql, function, triggers, pgadmin

I want to create a function with a trigger on a relation. The trigger is supposed to not let more than 3 datasets inside of a relation. Somehow the function I created gives an exception regardless of how many datasets are inside of the Relation.

Here is my Code for the Function. so it gives back Null which apparently is enough to raise the exception. How do I make it so that when there are less than 3 it does not raise the exception?

```
create function myFunction() returns trigger as $$
  Begin
    if exists(
            select case when count(*)>3 then count(*) end
            from person
            )
        then raise exception 'Just 3 Datasets allowed';
    End if;
return null;
End;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct:

```
if exists (select case when count(*)>3 then count(*) end
           from person
          )
```

always evaluates to `true`.  Why?  `exists` counts the number of rows returned by a subquery.  A query that is an aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one row.  If there are no rows in the underlying table, then the returned values would typically be `NULL`.

Note that `exists` doesn't care about the *column values* on the returned row.  So a row with `NULL` values "exists" just as much as a row with other values.  In fact, Postgres let's you return no columns at all!  (Although I personally find that syntax a bit awkward.)

I suspect that you intend:

```
if (select count(*)
    from person
   ) > 3
```

Comment: There you go, i didn't knew i could just exclude the exists from the functions syntax. 
Thanks !
Also yeah, SQL Syntax is quite a pain